# Beautifulsoup placing </li> in the wrong place because there is no closing tag

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to data scraping and am trying to pull data from within the `<li>` tags, but beautifulsoup keeps putting all the closing `</li>` tags at the very end of the code so its impossible to index. When viewing the page source I noticed that the web designer did not use the closing tags. I am guessing that is why the problem is occurring.

Website that I am trying to scrape: http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/country/bus2.html

Code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/country/bus2.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#since there are many ul tags we will find the cild of the tag we want and then go to its parent
ul = soup.find('br').parent.find_all('li')[2]
print (ul)
```

I was wondering if anyone could offer a solution or some insight as to a possible way to work around this.

Thanks!

Comment: based on the linked duplicate: try replacing the last 2 lines of your code with `ul = soup.find_all('li');

for li in ul:
    print(li.get_text(strip=True))` and see if you get your expected results.

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the help!